# Remove Auto-Generated advertisement script appended to the results returned by ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, ads

My site is hosted on somee.com.

I have used JQuery to send ajax requests.

On every ajax request the returned result is appended with the below text.

```
"<!--SCRIPT GENERATED BY SERVER! PLEASE REMOVE--> 
<center><a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a></center> </textarea>
</xml></script></noframes></noscript></object></layer></style></title></applet> 
<script language="JavaScript" 
src="http://ads.mgmt.somee.com/serveimages/ad2/WholeInsert4.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPT GENERATED BY SERVER! PLEASE REMOVE-->"
```

for example if on success of ajax call the server returns the following string : "Invalid Username and/or Password"

Then I get the following string :

```
"Invalid Username and/or Password <!--SCRIPT GENERATED BY SERVER! PLEASE REMOVE-->
 <center><a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a></center> </textarea>
</xml></script></noframes></noscript></object></layer></style></title></applet> 
<script language="JavaScript" 
src="http://ads.mgmt.somee.com/serveimages/ad2/WholeInsert4.js"></script> 
<!--SCRIPT GENERATED BY SERVER! PLEASE REMOVE-->"
```

Now I am comparing this string to the other string, So comparison returns false as this string contains the appended text.

Thus, my site is not functioning properly.

**EDIT** :

I counted the no. of characters and tried to use `.slice(0, -no. of characters in advertisement)`. This works fine if the server returns string. But does not work while server returns `'JSON'` because in the ajax call we have to declare `dataType:'json'` and after the addition of advertisement script the result is no more json object. So, Success is not called and as a result I did not get the output.

**So, now my question is :** If server returns `JSON + String` on AJAX call, on client side I want to `delete the String part` and get only the `JSON` object so that AJAX call returns in a success instead of failure/Error. (I know the no. of characters that the appended string contains.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then don't use datatype attribute, instead you should use jQuery.parseJSON.

Here is the example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/members/GetAllFileNamesOfSelectedUser?SelectedUserName=" + $("#AllowedFriends").find(":selected").text(),
   //dataType: 'json',
   success: function (FileNamesUnparsed) {
       var FileNames = jQuery.parseJSON(FileNamesUnparsed.slice(0, -369));
       $(".item").remove();
       $.each(FileNames, function (key, value) {
           $('#fileName').append($('<div class="item"><span>' + FileNames[key] + '</span> <img id="imgDelete" title = "Delete" src = "../Images/delete.png" /> </div>'));
```

Answer (score 5):

@Kushi, I guess that if you are asking this question, you first got rid of the automatic script on regular pages without any post back. Could you tell me how you did that please?

Thank you

I just figured it out so I edit my answer for other people who would be looking for it. It was not that bad finally :)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[style='opacity: 0.9; z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 65px; right: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: #202020; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;']").remove();
        $("div[style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 65px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; display: block; position: fixed; z-index: 2147483647; opacity: 0.9; background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);']").remove();
        $("div[onmouseover='S_ssac();']").remove();
        $("center").remove();
        $("div[style='height: 65px;']").remove();
    });
</script>
```

it worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove somee.com's advertisement,
store following code in to a .js file(eg. SomeeAdsRemover.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeeAdsRemover();
});

function SomeeAdsRemover() {
    $("center").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == '<a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a>') {
            $(this).next().remove();
            $(this).next().next().remove();
            $(this).next().next().next().remove();
            $(this).remove();

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

---

And then, Add following link in to your <head> tag:

`<script src="Scripts/SomeeAdsRemover.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

I just hide by CSS this block

```
center > a {
     display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply append a unique identifier with your ajax response.Then the return result should looks like YOUR_DESIRED_RESULT+"Uniqueidentifier"+"(Somee Auto-Generated advertisement)
e.g. var retUrl = "DESIRED_RESULT/Somee Auto-Generated advertisement".
Now split the result with unique identifier(here '/').
retUrl = retUrl.split('/')[0]; // this is your desired output; :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code at end page:

```
</html><noscript><title><style><layer><object><noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SomeeAdsRemover() {
    $("center").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == '<a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a>') {
            $(this).next().remove();
            $(this).next().next().remove();
            $(this).next().next().next().remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        }
        $("div[style='opacity: 0.9; z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 65px; right: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: #202020; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;']").remove();
        $("div[style='position: fixed; z-index: 2147483647; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 65px; right: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;']").remove();
        $("div[style='height: 65px;']").remove();
    });
}
```

[image: somee.com remove ads]

> My code to delete an "somee.com" div. And delete the code "web hosting
>   by somee.com" above.

Comment: Please take the time to [format your code properly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, ensure you provide an explanation of how your code works.

Comment: If you just modified code from the question or another answer, then please [explain](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) what you changed and why. If the code is from another answer and you are not changing much, then this may be better suited as a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

you can store following code in desired .js file (e.g adsRemover.js) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    adsRemover();
});

function adsRemover() {
    $('script[src="http://ads.mgmt.somee.com/serveimages/ad2/WholeInsert4.js"]').remove();
    $('script#last-script').nextAll('div').remove(); // last tag before </body>       
    $('center').filter(function () {
        return $(this).html() == '<a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a>';
    }).remove();
    setTimeout(function () {
        adsRemover()
    }, 500);
}
```

and then, add following link in to your  tag:

```
<script src="adsRemover.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code In Order To Remove The Somee Advertisement:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeeAdsRemover();
    adsRemover();
});

function SomeeAdsRemover() {
       $("center").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == '<a href="http://somee.com">Web hosting by Somee.com</a>') {
        $('script[src="http://ads.mgmt.somee.com/serveimages/ad2/WholeInsert4.js"]').remove();
        $('script#last-script').nextAll('div').remove(); // last tag before </body>   
        $(this).next().remove();
        $(this).next().next().remove();
        $(this).next().next().next().remove();
        $(this).remove();

        return false;
    }
});
}

function adsRemover() {
     $('body > div:last-child').remove();
   }
```

---

And then, Add following link in to your  tag with other Js:

`<script src="Scripts/SomeeAdsRemover.js"></script>`

### `http://www.cndesigns.somee.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up struggling with this issue for a while so just thought to share my solution. Apparently, Somee uses a dynamically injected script, so even if you end up using your own script with jQuery, the Somee Javscript will overwrite it.

Just use some CSS and modify accordingly, using the style selector since the divs have no id or class selectors.

```
div[style*="height: 65px;"] {
    display: none;
}

div[style*="opacity: 0.9; z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 65px; right: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: #202020; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"] {
    display: none !important;
}

center {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Since Somee constantly updates their scripts, I can't guarantee this will work for you, but it should be pretty simple to modify.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('center').hide()
});
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.